# Android errors in project while using appcompat v7

Tags: java, android, xml

I used appcompat v7 before. But Have not face this problem. Here's what i do. I add appcompat to my workspace and then chose it as a library for my project. When I try to run my project first I receives errors in appcompat styles file. I changed project build target of appcompat to 5.1.1 ( errors are resolved in appcompat). Now I received R errors in my project. I changed my projects compile versions but nothings change. I faced the same errors. In my console , There are alot of errors like this.

```
D:\Eclipse\Android\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:142: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
[2015-06-02 03:47:56 - NavDrawerWithCustomListview]
```

I refresh , build and clean my project many times. But still having same issue. Anybody have any idea about this?
One more thing I also update my support library yesterday. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are not using the last AppCompat library. Try to update last version (**com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0**) of support library on the Android SDK Manager and import it to your project. The attribute 'android:colorButtonNormal' appeared starting from v21.

Comment: With just that few info...is difficult to clarify something. But is not a good approach build appcompat as a library when you can already fetch it as a dependency. I recommend you to migrate your project to Android Studio. Is really straight-forward and you won´t have to take care about importing any android library. Eclipse is the past. Hope it helps!